# Deployed Cassandra in Docker, cannot connect with docker-cqlsh

Tags: docker, cassandra

as per instruction in Cassandra quick start page, but I'm stuck at opening the interactive mode and its throwing the below error

```
docker run --rm -it --network cassandra nuvo/docker-cqlsh cqlsh cassandra 9042 --cqlversion='3.4.5'
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 2816, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 2707, in read_options
    options.cqlversion, cqlvertup = full_cql_version(options.cqlversion)
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 540, in full_cql_version
    vertuple = tuple(map(int, ver_parts[0].split('.')) + [ver_parts[1]])
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'3"
```

we are just started learn cassandra, but we are struggling the early stages itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. I have cast a vote to have your post moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are following this guide [Apache Cassandra on Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html), After going through step 2 and running a container with Cassandra image like this:

```
docker network create cassandra 
docker run --rm -d --name cassandra --hostname cassandra --network cassandra cassandra
```

Instead of following step 5 as you are doing, you could just access the container in which your cassandra image is running using:

```
docker exec -it cassandra /bin/sh
```

Then go into interactive mode by typing

```
cqlsh
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace you posted seems to indicate that the script is not able to parse the CQL version.

Please check that you're not using special quotation marks when you specify `cqlversion`.

Which operating system are you using and which version? I've come across reports in the past that some versions of Linux have a Python version that doesn't seem to work with cqlsh. Cheers!